# UICollectionView with 2 separate design

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have `UICollectionView` and the selected cell should like the yellow one in pic. So how to have a separate design for the selected cell and how to draw that curve above it ?
Shall I use 2 separate `UICollectionViewCell` for this ? Or there is any alternate way to reuse the same cell on selection.

[image]

Comment: On a single cell make these 2 views. Then, detect the cell selection with didSelectItemAtIndex and change the view type for that particular cell.

Comment: you can change the background image for selected cell,take the image for selected cell and unselectes,whenever the user will select the cell just chnage the background image for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shall I use 2 separate UICollectionViewCell for this ?

That's one way to go. Do this if there are more differences than just the one you described.

> Or there is any alternate way to reuse the same cell on selection.

Sure, you can do that. Look at the two cells in your illustration, but consider that the grey part above each one as part of the cell. The black rectangle and yellow bulging rectangle are simply two different images that you draw in the background of the cell, and you can configure the same type of cell either way simply by changing that image. This is a good approach if other aspects of the cell, like positions of labels and such, are the same between both cells.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only different between that you want to make after selection, I think that there is no need to create two different `UICollectionViewCell`s, instead, you need to keep a reference on `indexpath.row`(s) of selected cell(s) and check if this is the selected row, change/add a new background image.

For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    // here is the variable that should save the current selected row...
    private var selectedRow: Int?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // let's consider that you have a custom cell called "MyCustomCell"
        // which has "backgroundImage" property...
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCellID", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

        // checking based on the selected row
        cell.backgroundImage = indexPath.row == selectedRow ? UIImage("yellow") : UIImage("default")

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedRow = indexPath.row
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Note that if you want to check on more than one row, you should declare a `selectedRows` as an array (or maybe as a set) of Ints.

Hope it helps.